# Forgot the plug part of my laptop charger but have the bulk part that connects to laptop, Can i use the plug part only?

Tags: laptop, adapter

Ok, To more clarify:

I thought i packed my whole charger with my dell laptop but come to find, the second half of it isn't with me, only the bulk part that connects to the laptop. I have another one but its for hp laptop. Is it possible for me to use the plug part of the hp and connect it to the bulk  -adapter part for a substitute? They are both 3 pronged (that connects to  adapter-not plug to wall part). Does it matter if the plug part is different but use the same adapter that came with the laptop?

(what i have with me) dell adapter without plug part- input: 100-240v~2.5A(2,5A) 50-60Hz
Output: 19.5V(19,5V)=7.7A(7,7A)

HP laptop adapter/plug- Input: 100-240V~1.5A(1,5A) 50-60Hz
Output: 19V(19V)=4.74A(4,74A)

Im think its okay to use the 3 prong plug to adapter as long as the adapter is made for the laptop. Ive read other forums about other people using the whole charger that isnt made for it, but had to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, the part from the wall plug to the laptop follows a [standard called IEC 60320](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320), and swapping an identical part from another brand should be fine as long as it fits.

Most laptops I've seen use a c5/c6 connector

[image]

though I've seen a c7/c8 connector pair in use too

[image]

As long as they're the same type, right genders, all they do is supply mains into the PSU and should work perfectly fine

Images from the article linked above.

Comment: OH nice! Glad my description was understandable! :D Yea, i was hoping it was alright because it was just the plug part that detaches rather than using the wrong adapter to charge a different laptop. THANKS A BUNCH! :D